# How can I customize GNOME from the terminal [I'm using Cubic]

Tags: gnome, fonts, iso, customization

I'm trying to customize an Ubuntu Desktop 22.04 LTS ISO from the Cubic app.

I have a few commands that do the job I want, but apparently in the terminal provided by Cubic to modify the system they don't work...

The commands are the following:

- gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme "Yaru-red-dark"
- gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface icon-theme "Yaru-red-dark"
- gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface color-scheme 'prefer-dark'
- gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock extend-height false
- gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock dock-position BOTTOM
- gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock dash-max-icon-size 36
- gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface document-font-name 'Product Sans 11'
- gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface font-name 'Product Sans 11'
- gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface monospace-font-name 'Ubuntu Mono Regular 11'
- gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences titlebar-font 'Product Sans Bold 11'
- gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface text-scaling-factor 0.95
- gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock show-trash false
- gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock show-mounts false
- gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock show-mounts-network false
- gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock show-mounts-only-mounted false
- gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.ding show-home false

When I put any of the above commands I get the following error:

- error: **Cannot autolaunch D-Bus without X11 $DISPLAY**

I am someone new to this and I don't know exactly why this happens.

I would appreciate if someone could tell me how to change the GNOME settings so that when I install the ISO all my custom settings are applied.

I will be attentive to respond to people who help me, thank you very much!

Comment: I have no idea what the Cubic app is. You may want to edit your question and include some explanation. These `gsettings` commands act on the dconf database of the currently logged in user. You will surely be successfull attempting this through ssh.

Comment: Have you had a chance to look at the Cubic web site? (It is accessible from the hamburger menu in Cubic).